# Firefox offset wrong, unless I clear my cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I honestly do not get wtf is going on here if anyone understands what I'm doing wrong please help.

I'm trying to grab the offset of a div

```
var $offset = $('#wrapper').offset().top;
```

It's a wrapper div and the offset on chrome is 669.XXXpx

In firefox it's about 87px different from this number now here's the odd part.  If I clear my cache, firefox get's the number right.  Then it keeps getting the number right for about 5 or 6 refreshes....then it starts getting it wrong again.  But if I hold down

```
 <shift> + <ctrl> + r
```

...boom...it's right again. At first I thought Firefox was holding the $('#wrapper'); var in a cache or something like that, but I stopped caching that var and I'm just calling it right where I need it...and that didn't help.

I've tried a bunch of different things and the function that calls this is the absolute last line of my last javascript file and it's wrapped inside a document.ready so it should be the absolute last thing executed and the page should be set up correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: The cache doesn't interfere with JavaScript. Odds are you have some other resource which is slow-loading, but once it has loaded it's messing up your script. Maybe an image or another script. Can't say more without more code.

Comment: you know what, I just got up walked away from my desk and said to myself...I should throw a setTimeout() on there to see what happens...and it worked.  Aaaannnd now to trace the slow script...damnit.

Answer (score 0):

slow loading script....in my frustration I didn't think of it till I took a step back.